# Inject XML into a node using a string

Tags: php, xml, string, simplexml

I am rebuilding a nodes children by saving them out to an array as strings, trashing them in the XML, inserting a new child node into the array as a string...  now I want to loop through the array and write them back out to the original node.  The problem is I can't find anything on how to add a child node using a string.

See below for my code. Thanks!!!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $questionGroup = $xml->qa[intval($id)];

    $children = array(); //  create empty array

    foreach ($questionGroup->children() as $element) {  //  loop thru children
        array_push($children, $element->asXML()); // save XML into array
    }
    //unset($questionGroup->answer);
    //unset($questionGroup->question);

    //create new node
    $newNode = '<answer><title>'.$title.'</title><description>'.$description.'</description><subName>'.$subName.'</subName><date>'.$date.'</date><timestamp>'.$timestamp.'</timestamp></answer>';

    echo "children count: ".count($children);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    print_r($children);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    // insert new
    array_splice($children,intval($elementIndex),0,$newNode);
    echo "children count: ".count($children);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    print_r($children);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo $questionGroup->asXML();
    foreach ($children as $element) {  //  loop thru array 
        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo $element;
        //$questionGroup->addChild(simplexml_load_string($element));  //  add array element to the empty questionGroup

    } 
        echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "questionGroup: ".$questionGroup;
```

UPDATE:
I found a function that I modified and was able to get working:

```
function append_simplexml(&$simplexml_to, &$simplexml_from)
{
   $childNode = $simplexml_to->addChild($simplexml_from->getName(), "");
    foreach ($simplexml_from->children() as $simplexml_child)
    {
       $simplexml_temp = $childNode->addChild($simplexml_child->getName(), (string) $simplexml_child);
       foreach ($simplexml_child->attributes() as $attr_key => $attr_value)
       {
          $simplexml_temp->addAttribute($attr_key, $attr_value);
       }

      // append_simplexml($simplexml_temp, $simplexml_child);
    }
}
```

With this usage in my foreach() loop:

```
foreach ($children as $element) {  //  loop thru array 
    append_simplexml($questionGroup, new SimpleXMLElement($element));
}
```

Comment: You should add it as answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a function that I modified and was able to get working:

```
function append_simplexml(&$simplexml_to, &$simplexml_from)
{
   $childNode = $simplexml_to->addChild($simplexml_from->getName(), "");
    foreach ($simplexml_from->children() as $simplexml_child)
    {
           $simplexml_temp = $childNode->addChild($simplexml_child->getName(), (string) $simplexml_child);
           foreach ($simplexml_child->attributes() as $attr_key => $attr_value)
       {
              $simplexml_temp->addAttribute($attr_key, $attr_value);
       }

      // append_simplexml($simplexml_temp, $simplexml_child);
    }
}
```

With this usage in my foreach() loop:

```
foreach ($children as $element) {  //  loop thru array 
    append_simplexml($questionGroup, new SimpleXMLElement($element));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that with [`SimpleXML`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) alone. There is a nice way to do this with the [`DOM`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension and the [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) class. (Please note that I didn't try to understand your logic in the example provided, but you should be able to implement the simple sample below into your code).

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<root><parent/></root>');
// get the parent node under which you want to insert your XML fragement
$parent = dom_import_simplexml($xml->parent);
// create the XML fragment
$fragment = $parent->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
// append the XML literal to your fragment
$fragment->appendXML('<child id="1"/><child id="2"><grandchild/></child>');
// append the fragment to the parent node
$parent->appendChild($fragment);
echo $xml->asXML();
/*
 * <?xml version="1.0"?>
 * <root><parent><child id="1"/><child id="2"><grandchild/></child></parent></root>
 */
```

Links:

- [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php)
- [`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php)
- [`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php)
- [`DOMNode::appendChild()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php)
- [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asXML.php)

Comment: This sound very promising!  I'll give it a shot when I've got some spare time!  Thanks Stefan!!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$child = new SimpleXMLElement($newNode);

$yourxmlobject->addChild($child);
```

Comment: Now you still got to get rid of your old element, though, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I implemented this and it returned this error:

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]: Element name is required

addChild() needs a "name" and only creates (I think) a single, empty node using the passed "name".

I've got an array of strings, each looking like this:

<answer><title>blah 1</title><description>blah 1</description><subName></subName><date>4:34 pm, Wednesday, November 11, 2009</date><timestamp>20091111163453</timestamp></answer>

That I just want to inject into my empty node.

BTW, I'm using unset() to remove the nodes, but they are just commented out.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I misinterpreted something. Looks like you have to manually modify the values which should be much simpler and cleaner than the current approach anyways. Let me come up with something...